# Multiple fades in a CATTransition

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, catransition

I'm using a `CATransition` to create a fade effect on the `pushViewControllerAnimated` of a `UINavigationViewController`. This worked out fine with the following code:

```
CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.5;
transition.type = kCATransitionFade;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop;

[navController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
[navController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[navController pushViewController:nieuweDetailPagina animated:NO];
```

But because my views are very similar I would like to fade to white in between or show a white flash.

Is it posible to do it in the same transition or do I have to creat a UIView with a white background and start a simultanious animation?

Cheers!